# Sharesheet option in branch.io swift

Tags: ios, swift, url-scheme, branch.io

We are using branch.io for Deep linking in our projects, There is an latest version release on Feb 3. We can’t able to get the latest SDK options

> v0.31.4¶ (2020-Feb-03)
>
> - Add share sheet option to override placeholder URL. This allows more control over the iOS 13 preview header.

Link:https://docs.branch.io/version-histories/ios-version-history/

When the link is clicked the link will navigate to the App Store for the respective app it’s the current flow. When the link is long pressed it will ask to share via option.

What’s mean by share sheet option here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Share sheet option provides the user multiple options to share the link from within the app.
This is a Branch share sheet with options of messaging/social apps and also to save the link on the clipboard.

You can refer to our documentation here : https://docs.branch.io/apps/ios/#share-deep-link

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks @promit.dey.